# Where did this text come from in my edit?

Tags: bug, edits

I've edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833736/how-to-highlight-items-by-code-in-applicationmenu-wpf) question to format the code in the question text. However after finishing my edit, I found that there is a green highlight on the text "and image" and it hasn't been in the existing question on the left. But I haven't added this text to the question, so where did it come from?

[image]

EDIT:
I have checked the question again, and the asker has removed the "and image" that was added.

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue with another concurrent edit?

Comment: I would guess the OP posted with "and image" in the question. Then they edited it out within the 5 minute grace period. If you started your edit before their change, then it would look like you'd added it.

Comment: @resueman I thought so at first, but then I checked the edit history and found that the edit in which the OP has removed the "and image" already had my edits included. So does that contradict with what you're saying ?

Comment: @user3340627 If they did an edit within the first 5 minutes, then it wouldn't show up in the revision history. Whatever their final revision was after 5 minutes would appear as though it was the original post. So the order I'm proposing is 1. They post with "and image." 2. You start your edit. 3. They remove "and image," which doesn't appear in the revision history. 4. You finish your edit. 5. They remove "and Image" again.

Answer (score 13):

From @resueman [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300842/where-did-this-text-come-from-in-my-edit/300911?noredirect=1#comment229084_300842) [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300842/where-did-this-text-come-from-in-my-edit/300911?noredirect=1#comment229096_300842):

> I would guess the OP posted with "and image" in the question. Then
>   they edited it out within the 5 minute grace period. If you started
>   your edit before their change, then it would look like you'd added it.
>
> The order I'm proposing is
>
> 1. They post with "and image."
> 2. You start your edit.
> 3. They remove "and image," which doesn't appear in the revision history.
> 4. You  finish your edit.
> 5. They remove "and Image" again.